# How do I persuade Edward Deegan to join my side before fighting Lorenzo?

Tags: fallout-4

After I finished fighting the Cabot family with Lorenzo, I noticed that Edward Deegan died as well, but I wanted him to live. How do I convince him to join my side so that he lives through the conflict?

Answer (score 1):

From [Edward Deegan's wikia page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Edward_Deegan), you are able to pass a speech check to convince him to turn on the Cabot family with Lorenzo.

> Depending on the outcome of the Secret of Cabot House quest, Edward can be convinced to turn against Jack and help Lorenzo. However, he will later comment on Lorenzo being crazy and and tell the player that he regrets his past actions. He also states that "he can't have second thoughts now."

I have personally done this, so I can confirm that this works. However, it's worth noting the following:

> Deegan is not essential after The Secret of Cabot House is complete, after siding with Lorenzo.

Thus, even if you do convince him, he can still be killed, so if you want him to survive, make sure you don't do anything to make him aggro towards you.

For the exact speech options you need to choose, see [the post here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/164592-fallout-4/73376979):

> After you free Lorenzo and return to Cabot's house Jack will ask you why you let his father free, choose "I was right" and then "Yes" and Edward will side with you and the crowned dad against the rest of the family.